# Странное поведение меню wordpress, где собака зарыта?

Tags: wordpress, menu

Создал меню:

fuctions.php

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'menu-1' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'fs' ),
) );
```

page-home.php

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu(array(
  'container'       =>'nav',
  'menu_class'      => 'first-links',
  'theme_location'  => 'primary',
  'item_wrap'       => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
  'depth'           => 1,
));
?>
```

Структура страниц
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Созданное меню
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, создается дополнительная страница 'Согласие на обработку персональных данных', которую я не добавлял в меню.
Если сделать эту дополнительную страницу дочерней главной, то благодаря `'depth' => 1` она не попадет в меню. Но по идее должно работать и без этого, а это какой-то костыль. Что не так, поскажите

Comment: Попробуй зарегистрировать так:

register_nav_menus( array(
  'menu-1' => 'Primary',
  'menu-2' => 'fs'
 ) );


wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'Menu main', 'container' => 'nav', 'menu_class'      => 'first-links', 'item_wrap'       => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>', 'theme_location' => 'Primary'));

Comment: @Павел, да, вы были правы, натолкнули меня на нужную мысль. Оказалось нужно было добавить 'menu' => 'Menu main', :  wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'Menu main', 'container' => 'nav', 'menu_class' => 'first-links', 'item_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>'));
сделайте это ответом, я помечу как правильный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить аргумент menu. Соответствие: id, слаг или название меню.

```
wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'Menu main', 'container' => 'nav', 'menu_class' => 'first-links', 'item_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>'));
```